# Visual Studio 2013, Sync 2 files in Source Control Explorer

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, synchronization

When I am editing a css or JS file that is in say a folder called **"Theme"**. How do i set up another folder say it is called **"ThemeBackup"** to **auto sync** its internal files.

**Example:**

If I edit **"Theme/css/mystyle.css"**. Then i want Visual studio to **automatically** checkout the file **"ThemeBackup/css/mystyle.css"** and make the same change i just made, **syncing** it with the original.

Aditional information:
I am using a ASP.net MVC4 Web Application

Comment: Hi Jacob, have you tried Github?

Comment: In normal circumstances i understand that would work, but these are highly classified files i'm dealing with they can only be on our server, and We are using TFS Source Control to manage our files.